# How do I identify which user initialized or created a session variable?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I am creating a sample project and I have initialized a Session variable after proper authentication using username and password, so that only one authenticated user can create/initialize that Session variable. What I need is to show a message to a user who created that Session variable, something like "Welcome admin".

How can I recognize that particular user?

Comment: A session is user specific. If the currently authenticated user has initialized the Session, you know it's the Admin. What have you tried? What's going wrong?

Comment: Why would you want to show that message to a user who didn't create the session variable?

Comment: Well each user owns his own session so what is there to recognize?

Comment: @sethflowers actually I want to show the message to the user who created that session variable..

Comment: hmmm @CyberDude may be there is a scenario where I want to run the code according to the condition i.e whether that session is created by that particular user or not.. Can some one refer me to a good tutorial.. thanks in advance

Comment: If you are already authenticating, and creating the session variable, can you not get the user name at the same place?

Comment: I need your suggestions, my question is if I am creating a Session then that will show not null to me (behind code) and null to others.. sorry little bit cody question  :(

Comment: As I said the session variables are "user-scoped". This means that if the variable is there it couldn't have been created by another user. So you just need to test if it's there.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [loginstatus.loginview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginview%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to show the welcome message - at this point, you can create a session to 'track' or what ever it is you want to do.

> ```
> <%@ Page Language="C#" %>
> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
>
> <script runat="server">
> </script>
>
> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
>     <head runat="server">
>     <title>ASP.NET Example</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>         <form id="form1" runat="server">
>             <p>
>                 <asp:LoginStatus id="LoginStatus1" runat="server"></asp:LoginStatus></p>
>             <p>
>                 <asp:LoginView id="LoginView1" runat="server">
>                     <AnonymousTemplate>
>                         Please log in for personalized information.
>                     </AnonymousTemplate>
>                     <LoggedInTemplate>
>                         Thanks for logging in 
>                         <asp:LoginName id="LoginName1" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>.
>                     </LoggedInTemplate>
>                     <RoleGroups>
>                         <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Admin">
>                             <ContentTemplate>
>                                 <asp:LoginName id="LoginName2" runat="Server"></asp:LoginName>, you
>                                 are logged in as an administrator.
>                             </ContentTemplate>
>                         </asp:RoleGroup>
>                     </RoleGroups>
>                 </asp:LoginView></p>
>         </form>
>     </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this :**

```
    //check particular session exist

    if (Session["loginName"] != null && Session["loginName"] == "yourAdminName")
    {
        //Give a welcome message for the user
    }
```

You can get **very good knowledge about Session** using **[This Article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net)**

Comment: thanks @sampath but can u please clear me with my last comment viz  I need your suggestions, my question is if I am creating a Session then that will show not null to me (behind code) and null to others.. sorry little bit cody question :(

Comment: Actually session object is a user specific one.So you cannot access other users session. But can access your session like above way.

Comment: Since when can `Session == null`? That check is completely useless. Perhaps you meant `if (Session["loginName"]!=null...`